# Loop over dataframe with two or multiple index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Location    Test#       Type        Parm1   Weight
M36         Test1       A           1.39    233
            Test2       B           1.44    281
            Test3       B           1.40    239
            Test4       A           1.49    438
            Test5       C           0.99    112
            Test6       C           1.74    200
            Test7       A           1.17    100
            Test8       A           2.40    7.8
M37         Test1       B           2.91    232
            Test2       A           20.2    0
            Test3       C           4.88    958
            Test4       A           9.46    0
```

I want to calculate weighted average for each location and add it as an extra column to the dataframe which should looks like this:

```
Location    Test#       Type        Parm1   Weight  Weighted Ave.
M36         Test1       A           1.39    233     1.434
            Test2       B           1.44    281
            Test3       B           1.40    239
            Test4       A           1.49    438
            Test5       C           0.99    112
            Test6       C           1.74    200
            Test7       A           1.17    100
            Test8       A           2.40    7.8
M37         Test1       B           2.91    232     4.495
            Test2       A           20.2    0
            Test3       C           4.88    958
            Test4       A           9.46    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, using `groupby`. This should be one of the more performant wats of doing it.

```
df.set_index('Location', inplace=True)                # set the index

df['Weighted_Sum'] = (df.Parm1 * df.Weight)           # calculated weighted sum
v = df[['Weighted_Sum', 'Weight']].sum(level=0)       # groupby + sum

df['Weighted Ave'] = v['Weighted_Sum'] / v['Weight']  # calculate the mean
del df['Weighted_Sum']                                # drop the surrogate column
```

```
df

          Test# Type  Parm1  Weight  Weighted Ave
Location                                         
M36       Test1    A   1.39   233.0      1.434275
M36       Test2    B   1.44   281.0      1.434275
M36       Test3    B   1.40   239.0      1.434275
M36       Test4    A   1.49   438.0      1.434275
M36       Test5    C   0.99   112.0      1.434275
M36       Test6    C   1.74   200.0      1.434275
M36       Test7    A   1.17   100.0      1.434275
M36       Test8    A   2.40     7.8      1.434275
M37       Test1    B   2.91   232.0      4.495933
M37       Test2    A  20.20     0.0      4.495933
M37       Test3    C   4.88   958.0      4.495933
M37       Test4    A   9.46     0.0      4.495933
```

To get the `Weighted Ave` column in your format, use `mask` -

```
df['Weighted Ave'] = df['Weighted Ave'].mask(df['Weighted Ave'].duplicated(), '')
```

Comment: Very close. But how I can get the format that I am looking? Meaning getting rid of duplicate Locations and Weighted Aves and having just one per location.

Comment: @Bob You're welcome. You could accept the answer if it was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: No sorry about that, I didn't mean it. I am new here; and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm now providing another way of using the `agg` function.

Basically the Weighted average can be calculated by using the `numpy.average` with the `Weight` column in the df provided as the parameter.

After which, just use `agg` to aggregate this `lambda` functions. which you could also use `apply`.

Finally, just use `join` to join back the weighted average to the original dataframe.

```
df["W_Ave"] = np.NaN
wave = lambda x: np.average(df.loc[x.index, "Parm1"], weights = df.loc[x.index, "Weight"])
f = {"Weighted Average": wave}
df_wave = df.groupby(['Location'])["W_Ave"].agg(wave)
del df["W_Ave"]
dffinal = df.join(df_wave, on="Location")
```

Finally Output:

```
dffinal
Out[38]: 
   Location  Parm1  Test# Type  Weight     W_Ave
0       M36   1.39  Test1    A   233.0  1.434275
1       M36   1.44  Test2    B   281.0  1.434275
2       M36   1.40  Test3    B   239.0  1.434275
3       M36   1.49  Test4    A   438.0  1.434275
4       M36   0.99  Test5    C   112.0  1.434275
5       M36   1.74  Test6    C   200.0  1.434275
6       M36   1.17  Test7    A   100.0  1.434275
7       M36   2.40  Test8    A     7.8  1.434275
8       M37   2.91  Test1    B   232.0  4.495933
9       M37  20.20  Test2    A     0.0  4.495933
10      M37   4.88  Test3    C   958.0  4.495933
11      M37   9.46  Test4    A     0.0  4.495933
```

And if you are just interested in the weighted average:

```
df_wave
Out[39]: 
Location
M36    1.434275
M37    4.495933
Name: W_Ave, dtype: float64
```